# Check datetime span for weekend

Tags: python, datetime, strftime

I have two datetime time points for some data. I want to know if a specific day and time of the week occured on or inbetween the points. I want to specifically know if (Fri 17:00) - (Monday 07:00) occured. I can check the specic points if its the days im looking for with strftime(%a). But this would not work with the span
*(Thursday 12/8) - (Monday 16/8)*

Is this possible to achieve somewhat easily?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the [datetime.weekday()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime-objects) method and [datetime.hour](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime-objects) attribute to check if your dates are in your desired range. No need to compare the string representation of the time points.